# Заполнить ассоциативный массив

Tags: массивы, php, foreach

День добрый знатоки!

Есть следующая задача.

Есть список дат в формате 2014-01-01 и есть фильтр для отображения новостей. Нужно вытащить из каждой даты месяц и год и на основе всех этих данных сверстать внешний вид фильтра. То есть мы берем все года и месяцы из этих данных и делаем выпадающий список, где при нажатии на год выпадает список месяцев.

Я беру эти даты, прогоняю их через цикл, вырезаю из них года и месяцы, записываю их по массивам и убираю повторяющиеся значения. Проблема возникает при формировании структуры фильтра. Мне нужно сначала вывести год, а затем под него запихать соответсвующие ему месяцы. Делал примерно так:

```
foreach($year_arr as $year)
{
   echo "<li>$year</li>";
   foreach($monthes as $month)
   {
       echo "<ul>$month</ul>";
   }
}
```

Но такая конструкция не сработает, потому что тогда он под каждый год выведет все месяцы. Поэтому я решил записать все данные в ассоциативный массив такого вида:

```
$date = array(2014 => array(01,03,05), 2013 => array(01,11,12)...)
```

И что-то я здесь застрял... Помогите сформировать массив такого вида. Как с помощью foreach и массива с датами так записать все в массив? Или может кто-то знает в принципе более удобный способ вывести такой фильтр? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arResult = array();
foreach($year_arr as $year)
{
   $arResult[$year] = array();
   foreach($monthes as $month)
   {
       array_push($arResult[$year], $month);
   }
}
```

В итоге получишь массив, ключами которого являются года, а значения это массив месяцев.
А потом просто пробегает циколом:

```
foreach($arResult as $key=>$value){ ...... }
```

Comment: Вот тут инфа о том, как связать два селекта http://www.cyberforum.ru/javascript/thread939298.html

Comment: Спасибо большое :) Но суть проблемы была именно в том, что нужно использовать списки, а не селект.